# Joomla update query not working

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I got a very strange problem with my queries. I try to update an article via code, but if I try to run the query nothing happens. When I echo the query and put that manually in my PHPMyAdmin it just works. I'm using chronoforms custom code to make a form to change an article. Here is the code:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "
SELECT *
FROM `#__content`
WHERE `id`='203'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$data = $db->loadAssocList();

$countArticles = count($data);

if($countArticles > 1){
    $articlesIDarray;

    for($i=0; $i < $countArticles; $i++){
        $articlesIDarray.push($data[$i]['id']);
    }

    $latestIDnumber = max($articlesIDarray);
} else {
    $latestIDnumber= $latestArticle['id'];
}


//Catid update

$query2 = "
UPDATE `jos_content` SET `catid` = '".$form->data['category']."' WHERE `id`='203'";
$db->setQuery($query2);

echo $query2;
```

And that echo generates this:

```
UPDATE `jos_content` SET `catid` = '14' WHERE `id`='203'
```

Which is a valid MySQL command in PHYMyadmin. Does anyone know if Chronoforms is the issue, or do you need to do osmething else with an update via db?

Comment: Pretty sure that whatever JFactory actually is, it will likely provide methods to check the success of database queries and/or ask the database what the problem/error was. So why aren’t you using any of those in your code …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run $db->query();
after you run $db->setQuery($query2);

$db->query() will return a boolean variable, indicating wether your update was successfull or not

Comment: That something so simple as that can be forgotten. How incredibly stupid of me. Thanks.